# The question number counter is funky

Tags: support

I swear the question counter on our main page is messed up. I checked last week and it said 234, and now it says like 201. Does it not go over 299? Or does it cycle weekly or something?

Comment: Many of the initial low quality questions have been deleted.

Comment: @J.Musser Oh wow that many?

Comment: Using the method: 'search "is:q" to get the extant questions, "is:a" to get the extant answers, add the numbers up, divide by the Id number of the most recent question', 63.3% of the posts here have been deleted. You can compare that with the 51.6% deleted on Sceptics.

Comment: Credits for the numbers shown above go to [Behaviour](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/147263/behaviour) from Math.se.

Comment: @J.Musser Post IDs also include tag wikis and excerpts. At the moment, there are 203 non-deleted questions, 575 non-deleted answers, and 104 live tags = 208 posts. Add a number of tags that were renamed.

Comment: Yeah, I lost 220 reps because of deleted questions. Who did lose more?

Answer (score 5):

I deleted a whole bunch of closed questions yesterday when the site entered public beta. Others probably did as well. It's generally a good idea to clean house a bit before new folks show up.